# Solve using for and while loop

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

Write a program that displays a conversion table from Fahrenheit to Celsius. The program must request the starting Fahrenheit value, the ending Fahrenheit value, and the increment. Thus, instead of the condition checking for a fixed count, the condition checks for the ending Fahrenheit value.

Comment: Yes, that's your assignment. If you want to ask a question about it here, you'll have to be specific on what you tried and what you're having trouble with -- ideally with tags to indicate what language you intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 double startValue = sc.nextDouble();
 double endValue = sc.nextDouble();
 int inc = sc.nextInt();

for(double i=startValue;i<=endValue;i+=inc){


double  celsius = (i - 32) / 1.8;
System.out.println(celsius);

}
```

Comment: So we need to print Celsius here right?

Comment: yup, I have printed celsius in this code snippet. You can print as you want .